# Symfony Sylius Admin : Invalid csrf token

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing a site with Symfony 4 and I'm using Sylius for administration.
I would like to add the action that allows you to delete a customer.

To be done I added the following code:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_admin_customer:
            actions:
                item:
                    delete:
                        type: delete
                        options:
                            link:
                                route: sylius_admin_customer_bulk_delete
```

Unfortunately when I perform this action, I have this error:

`Invalid csrf token.`

The exception is the following :

Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: "Invalid csrf token." in \vendor/sylius/resource-bundle/src/Bundle/Controller/ResourceController.php

I do not understand why it does not work when I try to do this action. If anyone can help me solve this problem, it would help me to move forward

Thank you

Comment: Do you have CSRF protection enabled in your Symfony project? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#reference-framework-csrf-protection

Comment: @BartoszZasada yes, I have CSRF protection enabled in my project